# PHP/MYSQL/JSON: Tweak api for parsing in IOS app

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to follow [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) tutorial to parse a `JSON` `web service` for display in an app.

The tutorial takes the input for loans from a service called `KIVA` as follows:

```
{"loans":[{"id":961236,"name":"Alhassan","description":{"languages":["en"]},"status":"fundraising","funded_amount":0,"basket_amount":0,"image":{"id":1960690,"template_id":1},"activity":"Personal Purchases","sector":"Personal Use","themes":["Rural Exclusion"],"use":"to buy food and clothing, eliminating pressure to sell maize for low prices at harvest","location":{"country_code":"NG","country":"Nigeria","town":"Kaduna","geo":{"level":"town","pairs":"10 8","type":"point"}},"partner_id":288,"posted_date":"2015-10-13T21:00:03Z","planned_expiration_date":"2015-11-12T21:00:03Z","loan_amount":200,"borrower_count":1,"lender_count":0,"bonus_credit_eligibility":false,"tags":[]}
```

The current output from my service is:

```
[{"userid":"1","shcom":"hello","lcom":"hello there friend"}]
```

The main thing I think my web service is missing relative to the one above is:

"loans":`[ at the beginning of the output.

So I think what I need to do is insert that at the beginning of the `JSON` output as the `objective-c` code in the app uses "loans" to create an `array` as follows:

```
  NSArray* latestLoans = [json objectForKey:@"loans"]; // gets JSON

    NSLog(@"loans: %@", latestLoans); // Prints it
```

What would I need to do to my PHP code to print out JSON as in the tutorial?

Thanks for any suggestions:

Edit:

```
PHP:

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $loans[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Please update your post and include your `php` code which generates the `json` output. by what you have posted, it seems that you are looking for a key named _loans_ in your `json` which apparently is missing in your `json`. so, in the `php` file, you have to add a `key` named _loans_ and assign whole generated string for your out put(which you have included in your post right now) to it as it's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here was to change

```
$loans[] = array('$loan);
to:

$loans[] = array('loans'=>$loan);
```

This inserts the 'loans' at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

It is a `JSON` **object of arrays**, you need to adjust like the following:

```
$loans = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $loans['loans'][] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($loans);
```

Note:

- The `JSON` needs to be valid, the one you posted isn't
- Use PDO if you can, mysql_ is deprecated

example in PDO:

```
echo json_encode(array('loans'=>$stmt->fetchAll()));
```